# From initial View Controller how to segue acriss to a UITabBarController and use prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uitabview

Here is the setup:

1) Single View Controller - inital Cobntroller =  with a button.

2) Tab Bar Controller controller with 1 View Controller - Label

When I press the button it will segue over to the Tab View.

Now I want to use the prepareForSegue to pass over a String to update the label of the 1 View Controller inside the Tab Bar Controller.

When I do this I get a

"unrecognized selector sent to instance".

So I cab segue to the Tab View Controller.

However I am not able to reference the ViewController inside the Tab.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Post the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot segue from a single view to a TabBarController. Instead, use code like this:

```
- (IBAction)setupTapped:(id)sender {
    static NSString *tabViewControllerIdentifier = @"SetupViewController";  


    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:tabViewControllerIdentifier];
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIViewController *currentController = app.window.rootViewController;
    app.window.rootViewController = controller;
    app.window.rootViewController = currentController;

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view.window
                      duration:0.75
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:^{
                        app.window.rootViewController = controller;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}
```

That will transition between controllers. You can change the animation type to suit your purpose. This is set with the options parameter; currently showing UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight.

"SetupViewController" is the Storyboard ID (without the quotes) entered into the identity inspector (3rd icon from the right) for the TabViewController. You can change this to match what you have entered.

Comment: What is the tabViewControllerIdentifier ? I assumed that was the "View Controller" which is located inside my TabViewController ? For this view I have given it a controller called "TabViewController" This code generated following error "doesnt contain a view controller with identifier 'TabViewController'.

Comment: In your storyboard, when you click the ViewController, the identity Inspector (3rd icon from the left) has a field called Storyboard ID. This is the identifier to use. In the example above, the tabViewController has a Storyboard ID of "SetupViewController" (without the quotes).

Comment: thanks. But if I dont put the identifier "SetupViewController" in my intial View Controller then I get the error "doesnt contain a view controller with identifier SetupViewController".   If I update the StoryBoard ID in my initial view controller then the app does not crash but nothing happens when I press the button.

Comment: For this to work, you must put something into the StoryBoard ID for your TabViewController, the storyboard ID for the initial ViewController is optional. After you do this, replace "SetupViewController" in the method with the ID you give to your tabViewController

Comment: ok so after more testing I found this works perfectly for transitions between Single View Controller to another Single View Controller. However it does not work when going to Tab view Controller.

Comment: i got there in the end. Thanks alot for your patience and good explanation.